# If < formula is not working on all my cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to determine if my players play slots or tables based on if they have higher slot or table points.I typed in the formula =IF(D2

Comment: Are your cells formatted at text? Select the cell that you want your formula to go, and hit CTRL+1. Make sure it's formatted as "General". Then add your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

> IF(A1 > A2, "Slots", "Tables")

where A1 contains slot points, and A2 contains table points.

But the important thing here is to make sure you have the point numbers stored as `Number` not `Text`.